# FOSUserBundle login system doing nothing

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

I have installed FOSUserBundle in my project following all the steps from the official documentation, but login does not work.
When I submit in the login form, it comes back to the login page. No errors, no notifications, nothing.

My code:

security.yml

```
security:
    encoders:
        FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: sha512

role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
    ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: ROLE_ADMIN

providers:
    fos_userbundle:
        id: fos_user.user_provider.username

firewalls:
    main:
        pattern: ^/.*
        anonymous:    true
        form_login:
            login_path: /login
            check_path: /login_check
            provider: fos_userbundle
    login:
        pattern:  ^/login$
        security: false

access_control:
    - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/login_check, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/, roles: ROLE_USER }
```

config.yml

```
fos_user:
    db_driver: orm # other valid values are 'mongodb', 'couchdb' and 'propel'
    firewall_name: main
    user_class: Cdp\CoreBundle\Entity\BackendUser
```

user class

```
namespace Cdp\CoreBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="backend_users")
 */
class BackendUser extends BaseUser {

  /**
   * @ORM\Id
   * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
   * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
   */
  protected $id;

  public function __construct () {
    parent::__construct();
  }
}
```

routing.yml

```
fos_user:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/all.xml"
```

Kind regards, 
Jesús.

Comment: Any error in php logs ? In Symfony prod / dev logs ?

Comment: I don't see any error in php logs and Symfony logs.

Comment: you've added the bundle to `app/AppKernel.php`?

Comment: Yes I did. I don't get an error. That's the thing. By clicking on submit, the login page is loaded again and nothing happen. Very weird.

Answer (score 0):

Please, read the [documentation](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md) carefully:

> Pay close attention to the name, main, that we have given to the firewall which the FOSUserBundle is configured in. You will use this in the next step when you configure the FOSUserBundle

Then simply try to comment your *login* firewall. hope it will help.